# Cosa sono i "Sorrisetti d'oro"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> Quando mi svegliavo, pioveva smisuratamente e accanto a me, circonfusa da alati **Sorrisetti d'oro**, c'era Madonna Piumino, la più bella creatura d'allora, con la parrucca bianca.

Si tratta di nuovo di fantasticherie dell'io narrante.

La mia domanda è su questi "Sorrisetti d'oro" che appaiono in questa frase. Ho cercato questa espressione su Internet,  ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Comment: Probabilmente si riferisce agli angioletti d’oro che solitamente circondano le statue o rappresentazioni della Madonna

Comment: Mi viene da pensare che sia usato come sinonimo di putto (chiamato anche amorino).

Comment: Quelli rappresentati spesso come solo una testa e le ali? Non sono cherubini? (Non sono un esperto di gerarchia angelica.)